# Assistance installing IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

My laptop came with IE 11 on it and for my job I need IE 9 I tried uninstalling IE 11 and then downloading IE 9 but Microsoft will not allow the download.  Could anyone please help me?  I never had IE 9 on this computer so I cannot just revert back

Comment: Pussible duplicate: [How to run Internet Explorer 7 on Windows 10](//superuser.com/q/1019776)

Answer (score 0):

If the Microsoft website is not working, you should be able to download the file from a third-party source such as Softonic: http://internet-explorer-9.en.softonic.com/

Note that IE 9 only supports Windows 7, so if you are on another OS, it probably won't work.

However, both IE 11 as well as many other browsers allow you to change the user agent of your browser to trick the website into thinking that you are using IE 9.
Please refer to this link: http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/